# Is there a way to enable both Objective-C mode and C++-mode at the same time in Emacs?

Tags: c++, objective-c, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I'm working with some Objective-C++ code (`.mm` files), and I'm curious if it's possible to get emacs to use proper syntax highlighting for both the Objective-C parts and the C++ parts.  `objc-mode` and `c++-mode` are both major modes (built on top of `cc-mode`), so they can't be used at the same time.

Are there any minor modes or elisp hacks available to enable both Objective-C and C++ syntax highlighting at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this myself, but since all those modes are based around cc-mode it seems as though you could get the source code for objc-mode styles and c++-mode and combine them.

Another possibility would be to try out an alternate objc-mode that it supposed to be more advanced, perhaps it would better take c++ into account:

http://www.foldr.org/~michaelw/objective-c/

(scroll to the end and look for obj-c-mode.el)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes) a page that has information about running multiple major modes. As far as I know it's mostly used for doing web-type stuff where you might have several different languages in a single document, but It could probably work for others as well.

Comment: That page is about where you have code in multiple languages intermixed in one buffer; what's wanted here is to be able to enable support for two "extensions" of the C language at the same time.  (Yes, I know C++ isn't really an extension of C, but I don't think this fact matters much to `cc-mode`.)